# Why Image is not being served by django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to display image from the django database. in database image link of directories is also given correct. but when I opens that link it gives an error "TemplateDoesNotExist at /media/categories/abc.png"
even image is availabe at that link.

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
def upload_path(instance,filename):
    return 'categories/{filename}'.format(filename=filename)

class Categories(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    image_url = models.ImageField(blank=True, null = True, upload_to= upload_path)
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name','description','image_url']
```

**Settings.py**

```
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build/static')
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('auth/', include('djoser.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('auth/', include('djoser.urls.jwt')),
    path('auth/', include('djoser.social.urls')),
    path('adminuser/', include('adminuser.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += [re_path(r'^.*', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))]
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**Views.py**

```
class CategoriesListCreateAPI(GenericAPIView, ListModelMixin , CreateModelMixin):
    queryset = Categories.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategoriesSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def get(self, request , *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request , *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)

# Retrieve, update and delete (pk required)
class RUDCategoriesAPI(GenericAPIView, RetrieveModelMixin, UpdateModelMixin,  DestroyModelMixin):
    queryset = Categories.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategoriesSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def get(self, request , *args, **kwargs):
        return self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
    
    def put(self, request , *args, **kwargs):
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def put(self, request , *args, **kwargs):
        return self.partial_update(request, *args, **kwargs)
    
    def delete(self, request , *args, **kwargs):
        return self.destroy(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

here please look at my API [API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXkc4.jpg) after uploading image when I clicked that link "http://localhost:8000/media/categories/feed.png"

it gives me an error page.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtCzH.png)

Comment: Have you set up the correct URL routing? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

Comment: Yes it is already added

Comment: Show your `urls.py`, then. The error message looks like there's another route capturing your `/media/` requests.

Comment: Sir I have added. check please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URLs have

```
urlpatterns += [re_path(r'^.*', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))]
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

The first `re_path` captures every single request, so the static URL is never reached. Flip these around:

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) 
urlpatterns += [re_path(r'^.*', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))]
```